# I am trying to upload an image to cloudinary.But it gives me TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, cloudinary

my routes for uploading image and posting image:

```js
router.post("/create-post", requireSignIn, createPost);
router.post(
    "/upload-post",
    requireSignIn,
    formidable({ maxFileSize: 5 * 1024 * 1024 }),
    uploadImage
);
```

event functions for uploading only without content which works fine

```js
const handleFile = async (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("image", file);

        const token = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("login"));
        setLoad(true);

        try {
            const response = await axios.post(
                "http://localhost:8000/api/upload-post",
                formData,

                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token.token}`,
                    },
                }
            );
            const data = response.data;
            console.log(data);
            setImage({ url: data.url, public_id: data.public_id });

            setLoad(false);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            setLoad(false);
        }
    };
```

but whenever i try to post it using different routes by attaching some contents it gives me error:TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'image')
at uploadImage (/home/alanhub/react-projects/social-media/server/controler/post/post.js:30:63)
POST FUNCTION IS:

```js
const submit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const token = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("login"));
            const { data } = await axios.post(
                "http://localhost:8000/api/create-post",
                {
                    content,
                },
                {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token.token}`,
                    },
                }
            );
            console.log(data);
            if (data.error) {
                toast.error("ERROR OCCOURED");
            } else {
                toast.success("post created");
                setContent("");
            }
        } catch (err) {
            toast.error("something went wrong");
        }
    };
```

CONTROLLERS HANDLING THESE REQUESTS ARE:

```js
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
// const path = require("path");

cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET,
});
const createPost = async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    const { content, image } = req.body;
    if (!req.body.content) {
        return res.json({
            error: "Write something",
        });
    }
    try {
        const post = new Post({ content, image, postedBy: req.user._id });
        post.save();
        res.json(post);

        console.log(post);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("err");
    }
};
const uploadImage = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.files.image.path);
        console.log(response);
        res.json({
            url: response.secure_url,
            public_id: response.public_id,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};
module.exports = createPost;
module.exports = uploadImage;
```

Anyone help me its really giving me pain since a week

Comment: Do you know the content of `req.files` in your upload call? It looks like `req.files.image.path` is undefined. Comparing the 2 codes, the first one you are sending the file via form but on the 2nd one there is no definition of content, can you share it?

Comment: eq.files gives
{
  image: File {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
    _eventsCount: 0,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    size: 333384,
    path: '/tmp/upload_a9edccd2f2c43688353836b262ecb89a',
    name: 'A4 - 1.jpg',
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    hash: null,
    lastModifiedDate: 2021-11-25T12:42:57.295Z,
    _writeStream: WriteStream {
      ............

Comment: the main point is while hiting the endpoint /api/upload-post, it works fine and it also gives a response with public url.It stops working when hiting /api/create-post/ 
I am wondering why on button click for post(defined for the another endpoint) it executes the function defined for the end point /api/upload-post/